# Prove that relation R is an equivalence relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, relations, equivalence-relations

Let $A$ be a finite set (not empty) and $B$ a subset of $A$:

How to prove that relation

$R = \{(f,g) \mid f,g \in \{1,0\}^A, B \in P(\{x \in A \mid f(x)=g(x)\})\} $

is an equivalence relation?

Equivalence relation means that it must be a reflexive relation, a symmetric relation and a transitive relation.

How i can prove those three statements?

Thanks

Comment: What is the role played by $B$ in the definition of $R$? Actually, I don't understand your definition of $R$.

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco actually thats my problem i don't understand the definition of $R$ i think after understanding the definition the rest is easy

Comment: Here is a reformulation of the relation: Two functions $f$ and $g$ from $A$ to $\{0,1\}$ are in relation ($f \sim g$) if and only if $B$ is a subset of the set of points where $f$ and $g$ coincide (take the same value). In other words $f \sim g$ if and only if $f$ and $g$ take the same values on $B$.

Comment: @SebastianSchoennenbeck thats mean  $fRg$ $\iff$ $(f(x) \in B=g(x) \in B)$  for every $x\in A$ ?

Comment: No, what is that even supposed to mean? It means $fRg \Leftrightarrow (\forall x \in B: f(x) = g(x))$.

Comment: @SebastianSchoennenbeck oh i think now i got to prove reflexive  $∀x \in B : f(x)=f(x)$ ; symmetric  $∀x \in B : f(x)=g(x) $ and because $f,g : A \to \{0,1\}$ then $g(x) = f(x)$ and the same for transitive . Is that correct ?

Comment: Yeah pretty much. If this is a homework problem (or in an exam) you should give a little more detail, otherwise this is fine. However, you should really try to understand why what I wrote is equivalent to the definition of the relation.

Comment: @SebastianSchoennenbeck  okey, thank you

Comment: any idea how to find $|\{0,1\}^A/R|$ when $B=\{\}$ and when $|B|=k$ ?

Comment: If you have a follow up question you should open a new question and ask it there.